# Different ExpressJS Error for API vs Page Request?

Tags: node.js, express

What is the best way to detect if a request is for an API call versus a page request?  I'd like to render a view for page requests and send JSON for API requests.  For example:

Common error for page requests:

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('500', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}
```

Common error for API requests:

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.send({
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}
```

Thinking about using this but wanted other opinions:

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        if (req.url.startsWith('/api')){
            res.send({
                msg: err.message,
                err: err
            });
        } else {
            res.render('500', {
                message: err.message,
                error: err
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not fundamental difference between API calls and page requests except their headers. It could also depend on how you architecture your app/routes.

*I would suggest the following:*

**Solution one:**

Use a unique middleware that checks the content-type of the request headers:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (req.get('Content-Type') === 'application/json') {
        // API Stuff
    } else {
        // Page Stuff
    }
});
```

*NB: I assumed here that your API was of the JSON kind.*

**Solution two:**

1. [Create a router](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) on which you map all your APIs.
2. Mount this router and your special API middleware on a common route like

*Ex:*

```
app.use('/api', apiRouter, apiMiddleware)
```

Comment: Glad it helped :) if I were you I'd probably check if the content type starts with `application/`